# Display data stored in arraylist using jquery and html5

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, arraylist

I have one arraylist named resultset. I want to print that data to browser using jquery and html. I am passing that arraylist to one function viewCSV. I want to send that arraylist to the jquery page from taht I can print those elements.
Following is the method viewCSV:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewCSV", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void viewCSV(@RequestParam List<ArrayList<String>> resultSet) throws 
IOException {



}
```

How I can send data plz give suggestion. how to pass that data to for loop in following code

jquery code(details.js):

```
$(document).off('click', '#viewCSV').on('click', '#viewCSV', function(e) {
//var Number = $('#number').val();
var appendString = "<tbody id='bomRows'></tbody>";

var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "/viewCSV",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"             
        },
        //"data": partNumber
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    $('#bomRows').remove();
    $('#bomTable').append(appendString);


    jQuery.each(..............., function(-----) {
        jQuery.each(part, i) {

        }

        var idRow = "#bomRow";
        $('#bomRows').append("<tr id='bomRow'></tr>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.assembly+"</td>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.part+"</td>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.quantity+"</td>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.uom+"</td>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.findnumber+"</td>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.match+"</td>");
            $(idRow).append("<td>"+ ----.stepfail+"</td>");
    });
})

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show that array here ?

Comment: [[375-76646-102, 025-42860-000, 1, ea, 208, No, Quantity], [375-76646-102, 392-06208-009, 1, ea, 254, Yes]]

Comment: arraylist is somewhat like above with more elements

Comment: I want to modify jquery code also

Comment: Can you show the details in spring app-context.xml file? And also verify the url in ajax request is valid.

Comment: Where is `assembly`, `part`, `quantity` etc ?

Comment: in html page I have defined headers viewCSV.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a json and write it to a browser
If you are using spring mvc the annotation @ResponseBody will do this
So all what you need is to create a method annotated by request and ResponseBody and return list